# BannerBitmap is not showing in the Visual Studio Setup Project created Setup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation, setup-project

I have an image with dimensions as `500x70` and i have added this into welcome dialogue of the Visual Studio Setup project.My banner image name is `setup_banner.jpg` .I am able to build the setup project perfectly but while installation banner image is not getting displayed in the welcome dialogue of Setup project.

Please help me as this is driving me crazy.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jpg file is the same type as the default one. It's 500x70 but also 96 dpi resolution and bit depth of 32.

Comment: As per Your suggestion i checked my image and it is meeting all the requirement suggested by You.Still i am not able to see it in my installer.Also i am sure that it has been written over in `VsdUserInterface` because when i am trying to add this image again i am getting a pop up of `Filename already exists Do you want to replace. it?`.Please help.

Comment: What has vsduserinterface have to do with this? You go to each of the dialogs in the setup project in the user interface view, select the dialog, such as Welcome, then F4 (or right-click Properties windows) and the top choice is BannerBitmap where you browse to your bitmap to include in the build. Anything else sounds like a hack.